# How can I disable window minimizing on middle mouse button click in xubuntu?

Tags: mouse, xubuntu

It's very annoying especially when closing tabs in a browser. If a middle mouse button is pressed to often then you accidentally minimize a browser's window. That's not ok.

Answer (score 11):

To disable window minimizing on middle mouse button, run the following command in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'none'
```

To revert it back, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'lower'
```

To disable browser's  tab to close on middle click, see: https://superuser.com/questions/113048/how-do-i-prevent-firefox-from-closing-tabs-on-middle-click

---

You can also to use `xbindkeys`. To install it, run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

Then the next two lines must be placed in `~/.xbindkeysrc` file:

```bsh
""    #don't do nothing
b:2   #mouse button 2
```

And finally, you must to clear current bindings with `killall xbindkeys` and then just execute `xbindkeys` to restart it.

Comment: should I reboot after that?

Comment: @dhblah No, you don't need to reboot. You can check immediately the changes.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Nope.. the first of your suggestions does not work immediately. Some kind of restart or other action seems to be required.

Comment: After logout + login it works.

Comment: This doesn't work with the default Xfwm4 window manager. You have to switch to metacity to apply `gssetings`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Radu's answer, for those of us who actually want the windows to minimize instead of be sent to the background, this works:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'minimize'
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36

Answer (score 0):

To disable the window rollup on mousewheel feature: 
Open the Settings Manager
Scroll down to `Other` and select `Settings Editor`

Select the `xfwm4` option, and uncheck the `mousewheel_rollup` option. This should stop window shading when you accidentaly use your mousewheel near the titlebar.

Comment: should I restart after that?

Comment: actually, it prevents rollup when i scroll up near the title bar, that is nice feature, but I need to disable windows minimize on middle mouse button clicked.

Comment: There should be a different setting for middle mouse button click.

Comment: The question is about middle mouse button click, not about rollup on mousewheel.